# Bootstrap modal: how to fade in, but immediately disappear on close

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In reference to Bootstrap 3 modals: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

I use `class="modal fade"` on my outer modal div to create the default fade in/out effect of the Bootstrap modals.  But what I really want to do is fade in, but not fade out.  I want the modal to disappear immediately and completely when the close button is pushed, without any lingering CSS transitions.

**How can I remove the CSS transition when the modal gets closed, but keep it when the modal gets opened?**

Comment: Some background information: the web site I am working with sometimes opens up another modal as soon as the first one is closed.  If that happens during the period where the CSS fade-out transition is occurring, I see layout problems as a result (Bootstrap says never to open multiple modals at a time, and I think this is kind of similar).  By removing the `fade` class entirely, those layout problems are fixed, but the designers really want to keep that fade transition at least on opening the modal, where it wouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler for the "shown.bs.modal" event, and in that handler, remove the `fade` class.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#myModal').removeClass('fade');
});
```

The transition defined by the `fade` class will then not occur.

Comment: yep, worked perfectly.  thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `.fade` class and find another way to implement the fade-in, for example using a jQuery transition, that way you'll avoid forcefully overriding Bootstrap.

Comment: I don't think a jQuery transition would work here in connection with the Bootstrap CSS/JS (although feel free to prove me wrong if you have specific code to demonstrate it).